# Расшифровка utf-8, windows-1251 в email письмах

Tags: android, javamail

Здравствуйте.
У меня программа получает email письма с ящика. У писем, которые отравляются человеческими руками проблем нет, а вот у писем, отравляемых автоматическими различными сервисами, в графе "отправитель" информация выводится в кодировке. Выглядит это так:

```
=?UTF-8?B?*****
=?windows-1251?B?*****
```

Вытаскиваю отправителя из письма так:

```
public String getFrom(Message m) throws Exception{

    Address[] a;
    String result = "Ошибка загрузки";

    if ((a = m.getFrom()) != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        result = a[j].toString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

UPD:

Вот правильный алгоритм изымания отправителя из Java.Mail.Message

```
public String getFrom(Message m) throws Exception{

    String result = "Ошибка загрузки";

    Address[] froms = m.getFrom();
    result = ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно не совсем ваш случай но двигаться нужно в этом направление(если это не поможет гугли encode )

```
BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"windows-1251"));
byte[] utf8Bytes = res.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] defaultBytes = res.getBytes();

String utf8String= new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вопрос решен. Нагуглил другой способ получения отправителя и все стало отлично!